# Stored procedure w/ multiple optional parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was asked lately at work to perform many SQL Server stored procedures "adaptations". I can manage that but I am mainly a .Net developer so I have no idea what are good practices or if there's a better way to do things.

Briefly, here's the situation. We have many scripts that are runned nightly to avoid any impact on production. They scan multiple databases (linked servers and all) for special situations and add a record when such a situation is found. Each scripts does that, on all the databases (with millions of records) and there's over a hundred scripts that are runned this way.

Now, I was asked to change those script so they could accepted parameters and be called "on-demand" (no more nightly runs). Easy.

Where I'm, hesitant, is that they want the SAME procedure to be called but for different scenarios, each of which will pass it's own set of parameters and the query should then perform, to my understanding, some business logic to perform for that specific "scenario".

For example, the stored procedure will have these input parameters defined:

```
@PersonId, @OrderId, @OrderType, @RequestCode, ....
```

and probably some more.

When the stored procedure receive a `@PersonId`, I should return all the special situation for that person, but if the `@OrderType`, it should be all the situation but for that particular type. But, if it receive an `OrderId`, the stored procedure should return all the special situations for that order. If the `RequestCode` is provided, it should return all the situations, for every person, all the demands, linked with that code. There's like 4 scenarios to deal with, all of them should return the same data, but for different conditions.

And they specifically asked that there should be only 1 script (per special situation) to handle all the possibilities.

Like I said, right now that script is run nightly with no parameters on the entire databases.

I proposed to convert the script into code, so I could use all the good patterns, add testing, isolate them and everything. If I keep the "sql way", I'm scared that every little change will mean a whole lot more testing, and since we have access easily to programmers but the DBAs are such a rarity, having the special situations on-demand detected in .NET (which is where the request for detection will be called anyway...), having some classes and interfaces should be easier to maintain and evolve, even for a junior.

The requests no longer runs on every record, and there's not that much employees that would make those requests, especially not that many simultaneously. So I don't see a performance issue either?

I am a developer, so of course I bias. But if there's a good way to do what they ask of me (keeping everything in stored procedures, with many parameters, conditions and apparently some level of business logic), I'm more than ok with that too.

Sorry for the long post, thanks all, especially to those who will find time to spare some advice!

**EDIT :** Let say I adapt the script to handle all the possibilities, what would be the major impacts on testing, maintainability that you can foresee? Since I'm inexperienced, I think that, for such a "magic script than can do everything", debugging, testing and everything it would be a nightmare, but peoples here seems to ignore it. But they're not programmers nor they are DBAs, so I want to bring some reasons that could ring a bell and have them do things the right way, for now and the future, even if it would mean a higher cost at first. Thanks!

Comment: Having a single stored procedure that can do completely different things is a very bad design. It is like creating a method in dotnet that does something completely different depending on the parameters being passed. Just like your programming code you want your procedure to do one thing and do it really well.

Comment: I agree completely. I'm trying to get good advises from experienced DBAs so I can have some points to presented when we'll settle for good how we'll manage all this. Thank you.

Comment: This boils down to performance. An execution plan will be created for a stored procedure and stored in the cache. When you have multiple execution paths like this it totally destroys the engines ability to consistent generate an efficient execution plan. So even though the plan is great for one set of parameters it will be horrible for another. But it will use the plan that is already in cache if it  exists. If anything you can create a procedure as a "driver" and have it call various other procedures based on the parameters. This allows a good plan for each path.

Comment: So having one procedure for each of the 100's that could call "sub" procedures (which would always perform a single task and accept a subset of the main procedure parameters) could be an efficient alternative?

Comment: Sure that works just fine.

Comment: Great! At least I have pros and cons and an alternative. I you could resume that in an answers, I could accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a single stored procedure that can do completely different things is a very bad design. It is like creating a method in dotnet that does something completely different depending on the parameters being passed. Just like your programming code you want your procedure to do one thing and do it really well.

This boils down to performance. An execution plan will be created for a stored procedure and stored in the cache. When you have multiple execution paths like this it totally destroys the engines ability to consistent generate an efficient execution plan. So even though the plan is great for one set of parameters it will be horrible for another. But it will use the plan that is already in cache if it exists. If anything you can create a procedure as a "driver" and have it call various other procedures based on the parameters. This allows a good plan for each path.

Answer (score 0):

You added a lot of detail to your question, however, if you are asking how to handle optional parameters in a stored procedure then one way would be to include the absence of a value in your where clause evaluation. If the parameters are for filtering data then this flow would work. I will warn that having  `Mode`, `ProcessingType`, `Action`, `UpdateType` or `Operation` parameter types usually indicates a translucent operation.

Another thing to think about is how the query optimizer handles parameters. If the stored procedure is called many times using a similar set of parameters then the optimizer could choose a query plan that lends itself to the first or most used parameter sets. At some point later, you may pass a value that is the worse case scenario for the cached plan. This could lead to a situation where your "sub-second" stored procedure, out of nowhere, starts churning for very long periods of time. You can get around this with optimization and compiler hints, however, I suggest you read up on **parameter sniffing** as to be prepared in case you start seeing bizarre performance from your stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySPWithOptionalParams
     (@P1 INT = NULL,
      @P2 INT = NULL,
      @P3 INT = NULL)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE (@P1 IS NULL OR F1 = @P1)
      AND (@P2 IS NULL OR F2 = @P2)
      AND (@P3 IS NULL OR F3 = @P3)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm ok with having optional parameters, I can do that. What I'm looking for is a good way to adapt the script depending on those parameters. As Sean mentioned in a comment, I'm afraid of code that "can do everything", but not doing it good.

Comment: I agree with that statement as well.